# Gmail 'Send mail as' confirmation e-mail does not get delivered

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

I've setup a new gmail account `me.company@gmail.com` in order to use the gmail client to manage email from another account, `me@company.com.br`.

I'm receiving all e-mail that's sent to `me@company.com.br` in my `me.company@gmail.com` mailbox. Great.

However, I'm not able to "send mail as" `me@company.com.br` when using the `me.company@gmail.com` account. I added the `me@company.com.br` in the "send mail as" options, configured it like my colleagues here at the company (SMTP server, port 587, TLS), and I got the message that an e-mail had been sent to `me@company.com.br`. I tried resending the e-mail confirmation a zillion times using various different settings, but I never get that e-mail at the `me@company.com.br` mailbox.

Here is a screeshot of the "Save Mail As" settings:

[image]

After struggling for a while I noticed the following message in the `me.company@gmail.com` Spam box:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

     me@company.com.br

Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain company.com.br by company.com.br. [67.23.245.70].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-Verification failed for <send-as-noreply@google.com>
550-Previous (cached) callout verification failure
550 Sender verify failed


----- Message suppressed -----
```

What exactly is going on there? I'm having a hard time interpreting this error message.

ps: I replaced my username with 'me' and the company name with 'company'.

Comment: Add more details. Screenshots of the settings will be great.

Comment: Hi Rubén, my google account is in portuguese, so I don't think a screenshot will help much. In addition, I mentioned in the post the settings of the "save mail as" options in Gmail: port 587 and secured connection using TLS. The SMTP server is `mail.company.com.br`, and it's "not an alias" (though I tried using it as an alias too). I'm pretty much convinced the solution to this problem lies on the fail message I received in the spam box, which I pasted in the post. Could you specify the details you need in order to give me a hand? Thank you!

Comment: Just added the screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

You should talk with the email administrator of "mail.company.com.br" and ask him to change the settings of the email service in order to allow the email verification be realized.